# Goverment shutdown and the effect it would have on my current audit from where I filed my 2017 taxes in 2018

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, audit

My husband and I were audited last tax season. We had been working with the IRS all year providing them everything they needed to prove our return was legitimate.

About December 15th the take action bar had disappeared and the status return bar had shown back up. I assumed the audit was over because it had never done that all year.

Well the system shut down "for maintenance" and when it was available again it was 2019 so it would no longer allow me to check 2018 returns.

My questions are:

1. Does the government shutdown affect last year's audits or are they still being processed?
2. Since the take action had been removed and the status bar was placed back up, is our audit over? Before anyone says call, there is no phone assistance since the shutdown is in place.

Comment: What are the "take action bar" and "status return bar"?